# Adding logo in front of Bootstrap Navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add a logo in front of the Bootstrap Navbar - similar to the yellow logo on Peek.com but I want it on the right side of the navigation instead.

I am currently using this sample as a template: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/examples/hero.html
Instead of the Project Name, I want an image there instead. I tried adding some CSS so the logo is fixed to a spot.

```
.logo-fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 90px;
}
```

I added this after the body in the sample template:

```
<div class="logo-fixed"><img src="test.png"></a></div>
```

The logo shows but the top part of the logo is displayed behind the black navbar. Here is what it looks like:

[image]

How do I get it to display in front instead?

Answer (score 2):

Set the z-index on .logo-fixed:

```
.logo-fixed {
  z-index: 2000;
  ...
}
```

Or even better, don't have it overlap with your menu bar but instead have it be below it by setting your CSS top to something other than zero.

Comment: Thank you so much, I tried setting z-index but I didn't notice the value wasn't high enough (only set it to 1000)

Comment: Yes, looking at the sample, you can see the navbar's z-index is 1030. Good times. :)

Comment: Yea, in bootstrap for the classes fixed-top and fixed-bottom z-index is 1030. (Looked in bootstrap version 4.3.1.)